# How to double tap in logic node upgbe

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

how to make a double w key to jump, in logic node UPBGE

w + w = jump

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with this node setup:

[image]

[image]

Basically it works like this:

In state1 it waits for tapping w, if it is tapped, it changes to state2.
In state2 it jumps and sets it back to state1.